# Add a clickable UIButton to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

Is this allowed by Apple standards in `AppDelegate.m`?

```
- (void) addButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender
{
    PrivacyPolicyViewController *privacy = [[PrivacyPolicyViewController alloc] init];

    [_viewController presentViewController:privacy animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have a `_tabBarController` synthesised as a property in `AppDelegate` and added a `UIButton` (to make one tab be like Instagram's larger buttons in the tab bar).

How do I make the new `viewController` load?

Comment: App Delegate itself is not a view-based controller. What is `_viewController`?

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;

Comment: Why are you adding a button in the app delegate ? Why not add the button in the viewController.m ? The app delegate isn't meant of for this, it's purely there to handle app state changes (enter background, enter foreground etc...)

Comment: I have a tabBarController created there. Where else should I declare a tab Bar controller?

Comment: is there a better place to create a tab bar controller?

Comment: What button is that? The app delegate does not have a view (and hence no button). So it doesn't make much sense to put a method like `-addButtonPressed` in the app delegate. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I set up a tabBar controller that has a button over it in my appDelegate

Comment: @chris It is better to create a custom UITabBarViewController and do the UI relative actions in the view controller.

Comment: so I go create file -> MyTabBar inherited from UITabBarController and call that when I need it...a lot of googling seems to have people putting it in the appDelegate, which I agree seems wrong to me

Comment: In general you create a view controller (in your case the tab bar controller) in the view controller that *presents* it i.e. in the view controller with the button that triggers the presentation. As @CW0007007 said: You need to add this method to your `viewController.m`.